# MYSQL - How to select rows based on distinct values of a column?

Tags: mysql, jpa, spring-data-jpa

My question is similar to another stackoverflow post - [Select Unique Rows Based on Single Distinct Column - MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54252163/select-unique-rows-based-on-single-distinct-column-mysql)

but I have doubts on the answers

```
   +----+---------+-------------------+-------------+  
  | id | title   | email             | genre |   
     +----+---------+-------------------+-------------+    
  |  3 | test    | rob@hotmail.com   | 1         |    
  |  4 | i agree | hi@hotmail.com    | 2         |    
  |  5 | its ok  | hello@hotmail.com | 3         |   
  |  6 | hey     | what@hotmail.com  | 4         |    
  |  7 | nice!   | simon@hotmail.com | 5         |   
  |  8 | yeah    | when@hotmail.com  | 3         |  
  |  9 | hey     | how@hotmail.com   | 4         |   
  | 10 | nice!   | test@hotmail.com  | 5         |  
  | 11 | yeah    | last@hotmail.com  | 3         |
+----+---------+-------------------+-------------+
```

Expectation: select rows based on unique genre

```
+----+---------+-------------------+-------------+
   | id | title   | email             | genre |
   +----+---------+-------------------+-------------+
   |  3 | test    | rob@hotmail.com   | 1         |
   |  4 | i agree | hi@hotmail.com    | 2         |
   |  5 | its ok  | hello@hotmail.com | 3         |
   |  6 | hey     | what@hotmail.com  | 4         |
   |  7 | nice!   | simon@hotmail.com | 5         |  
   +----+---------+-------------------+-------------+
```

or

```
+----+---------+-------------------+-------------+
   | id | title   | email             | genre |
   +----+---------+-------------------+-------------+
   |  3 | test    | rob@hotmail.com   | 1         |
   |  4 | i agree | hi@hotmail.com    | 2         |
   |  6 | hey     | what@hotmail.com  | 4         |
   | 10 | nice!   | test@hotmail.com  | 5         |
   | 11 | yeah    | last@hotmail.com  | 3         |
   +----+---------+-------------------+-------------+
```

or

```
+----+---------+-------------------+-------------+
   | id | title   | email             | genre |
   +----+---------+-------------------+-------------+
   |  3 | test    | rob@hotmail.com   | 1         |
   |  4 | i agree | hi@hotmail.com    | 2         | 
   |  8 | yeah    | when@hotmail.com  | 3         |
   |  9 | hey     | how@hotmail.com   | 4         |
   | 10 | nice!   | test@hotmail.com  | 5         |
    +----+---------+-------------------+-------------+
```

i.e. any row with 1 , any row with 2 , any row with 3 ,...

Goal: Query should not return 2 rows with same genre.

If I use

> select * from...where ... group by genre;

I get error because of nonaggregated columns

I can add ANY_VALUE(that_column), it works  but do not know of any side effects.

select ...ANY_VALUE(that_column1), ...ANY_VALUE(that_column2) .... from ... where ... group by genre;

**Question**: I use Spring JPA , can I use this long query in my spring repository class
@Query( select....)
public List findData(..);

or is there an alternative efficient query ?

Thanks

Comment: *but do not know of any side effects.* The only possible side effect (in theory) may be that the values for different columns of one output row may be taken from different source rows... but I have never seen this in practice yet.

Comment: This is a huge (unacceptable) problem :) . so will manage in my code

Answer (score 0):

Here's a solution that will pick a row randomly from the group, while ensuring all columns returned by the query are from the same row.

```
SELECT id, title, email, genre
FROM (
 SELECT id, title, email, genre,
   ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY genre ORDER BY RAND()) AS rownum
 FROM MyTable
) AS t
WHERE rownum = 1;
```

This solution uses [window functions](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/window-functions.html), which are a new feature of MySQL 8.0. If you use an older version, you must upgrade (you should do this anyway, because MySQL 5.x is soon to be past its end of life).

Comment: Thanks Bill, I use cloudSQL, so probably still 5.7. I used java List to Map to find unique set. rownum = 1 means get only 1 row of each different value of genre?

Comment: You can check the version: `SELECT VERSION();` The meaning of rownum=1 means only one row from each group, since `ROW_NUMBER()` returns a series of unique integers starting at 1 in each group.

Comment: Google CloudSQL supports MySQL 8.0 since at least Sept 2020, but I don't know if your instance has been upgraded: https://www.infoq.com/news/2020/09/google-cloud-mysql-8/

Comment: Okay, so you won't be able to use the solution I proposed above unless you upgrade. I recommend upgrading sooner or later.